# ASP NET Core 2.0 + angular 4 json response handle

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular4-httpclient

I have the ASP NET Core 2.0 project. For client side I use angular 4. I try to implement api request handle on client side.

So, in my controller I have

```
public IActionResult AddWorkSchedule(int employeeId, [FromBody] WorkScheduleBaseRequest request)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

So, I'm waiting to get the array of errors on client side, but I've got this as text.[image]

I use net httpClient in agular 4 and call api like this

```
addWorkSchedule(employeeId: number, workSchedule: WorkSchedule): Promise<any> {
        return this.http
            .post('/api/employee/' + employeeId + '/workschedule/', workSchedule, { observe: 'response', responseType: 'json' })
            .toPromise();
    }
```

and handle it in my component this way

```
this.employeeService
    .addWorkSchedule(this.employee.employeeId, workSchedule).then(
    (success) => {
        console.log(success);
        },
        (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(error.error);
        });
```

My question is why 'error' property is text, not is array while error response, and how could I do to have it like array ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: but you are returning badrequest and not an array of errors. the answer is in your return. The error text is from your API validation

Comment: Even if I return response this way "return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, new[] {"error1", "error2"})" - I have no array

Comment: yeah that is because you are returning statuscode, to return an error you should return an array in your action and read it as json in you web/angular in the same way you would read any request/response from let's say database

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, this is bug of httpClient in angular 4. More details issue is described https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19888. In short - error response propery "error" has wrong type.

The solution I finish with:

```
this.employeeService
            .addWorkSchedule(this.employee.employeeId, workSchedule).then(
                (success) => {
                    console.log(success);
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse ) => {
                    let json = JSON.parse(error.error); // parse it to json as requested type is json
                    console.log(json); // json object
                    console.log(json.length); // json objects count == string errors count that came from server
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this._Http.post(this._baseUrl + "api/Employee/Create", this.CreateDTO.value,
            {
                responseType: 'text'
            }).subscribe(result => { alert(result) });
```

Adding {responseType:'text'} worked for me.